# Photoshop plugin to change hue/sat/val by holding a key and dragging mouse?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, plugin

I'm a beginner digital painter and am looking for ways to make my process more fluid.

Ideally I'd like a plugin that lets me change:

- Hue
- Saturation
- Brightness
- Brush size
- Brush opacity
- Brush hardness

By having a key for each that I hold, and then click and drag on my Wacom tablet.

I know that size and hardness can already be changed by using the alt key in a similar manner, but I want to do this for everything.

Any ideas? As a last resort I think I'll learn how to write plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a plugin sounds like a cool project, but before you do that, know that there is the [HUD colour picker](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/choosing-colors.html#choose_a_color_while_painting). You can assign it's keyboard shortcut to a [single key on your Wacom](http://tinytutorials.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/i-finally-found-a-use-for-my-wacom-express-keys/).

For brush size and hardness you are already aware that you can hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and drag left/right for one and up/down for the other. Assign that to a Wacom key too.

For opacity, well, you could map that to the Wacom pen's pressure or tilt sensitivity. But there's no hold-a-key-and-move-the-mouse type solution that I'm aware of.

Taken together, this should get you pretty close.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did know about the colour pickers, but you've convinced me to try out your setup before I go do anything crazy :P